# Typo3 extension builder configuration settings.yaml

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

i've got some problems with the extension builder, especially with the configuration.

The extension builder overrides all my changes ...

i've added in the configuration (`Configuration\ExtensionBuilder\settings.yaml`) the following code:

```
Resources: 
  Private:
    Templates:
      Fach:
        #Edit.html: keep
```

but that doesn't work ... everything will be overriten every time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comment out the statement.
use

```
Edit.html: keep
```

instead of

```
#Edit.html: keep
```